# Deviation of a plane curve from the $x$-axis

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, plane-geometry

I have a smooth plane curve $\gamma$ enclosed in a circle of radius $R$. See Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8vx5.png). I'm interested in measuring the deviation of this curve from the $x$ axis, denoted $\Delta(t)$ in the figure, as a function of the curvature. In particular I would like to bound $\max_{t} {\Delta(t)}$. I know the curvature of $\gamma$ is bounded by the curvature of the circle. Thus $\kappa(t) < \frac{1}{R}$. I originally tried to solve this by summing up the curvature along $\gamma$ but that gave $\int_{0}^{\Delta t} \kappa(t) dt < \int_{0}^{\Delta t} \frac{1}{R} dt = \frac{\Delta t}{R}$, which doesn't seem right.

EDIT:
I'm trying to bound $\max_{t}\Delta(t)$ as a function of the curvature $\kappa(t)$. Let $\tilde{\kappa} = \max_{t}{\kappa(t)}$. Then $\max_{t}{\Delta(t)}(\tilde{\kappa}) = 0$ when $\tilde{\kappa} = 0$, and $\gamma$ is a straight line (assume in this case the $\dot{\gamma} = \hat{i}$), and $\max_{t}{\Delta(t)}(\tilde{\kappa}) = R$ when $\tilde{\kappa} = \frac{1}{R}$, and $\gamma$ lies along the circle. What is the relationship for $\max_{t}{\Delta(t)}(\tilde{\kappa})$ for all other values of $\tilde{\kappa}$?

It is key that $\gamma$ is forced to pass through the black points on the sides of the circle shown in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8vx5.png).
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are after. According to what you've written, the curve could well be the the upper or lower boundary of the circle. Which means you cannot do better than estimating $\Delta$ by the radius of the circle. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Let me change that to $k(t) < \frac{1}{R}$. In which case, I'd expect there be some expression to how close can $\gamma$ get to the boundary without touching the circle as a function of the curvature.

Comment: Would this be an example of $\gamma$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wjhgzhqdpj

Comment: No, the curvature of that curve is greater than the enclosing circle. More like $h(x) = \frac{\left(-x^2+1\right)}{2}$.

Comment: Since $\gamma$ has to stay inside $B_R$, you should be able to establish that any circle of radius $1/\bar\kappa$ tangent to $\gamma$ does not cross $\gamma$ (using something like an ODE comparison theorem). From there you can use these "circular barriers" to get the kind of result you want - the thinner the region between the barriers gets, the closer to horizontal the initial velocity has to be in order to reach the opposite point on the circle. This will *not* give you the *optimal* bound on $\Delta$, but it'll give you something.

Comment: I suspect the optimal bound is achieved by a circular arc through the two endpoints with curvature $\bar \kappa$, but I'm drawing a blank on how to prove this at the moment.